# Errno 65 No route to host GoogleAppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine

i am trying to deploy a site to GoogleAppEngine
my app works fine on localhost:8080 using this command

dev_appserver.py /Users/wasif/Downloads/maidinstyle

but when i try to deploy it on googleAppEngine

```
 appcfg.py update helloworld/
```

i get these errors

```
wasifs-MacBook-Pro:Downloads wasif$ appcfg.py update maidinstyle/
04:32 PM Application: maid-in-style; version: 1
04:32 PM Host: appengine.google.com
04:32 PM 
Starting update of app: maid-in-style, version: 1
04:32 PM Getting current resource limits.
2014-09-07 16:32:51,909 ERROR appcfg.py:2411 An error occurred processing file '': [Errno 65] No route to host. Aborting. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/wasif/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/appcfg.py", line 126, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/Users/wasif/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/appcfg.py", line 122, in run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "/Users/wasif/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 5360, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/wasif/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 5351, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "/Users/wasif/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 2978, in Run
    self.action(self)
  File "/Users/wasif/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 5008, in __call__
    return method()
  File "/Users/wasif/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 3771, in Update
    self._UpdateWithParsedAppYaml(appyaml, self.basepath)
  File "/Users/wasif/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 3824, in _UpdateWithParsedAppYaml
    self.UpdateVersion(rpcserver, basepath, appyaml, APP_YAML_FILENAME)
  File "/Users/wasif/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 3709, in UpdateVersion
    return appversion.DoUpload(paths, openfunc)
  File "/Users/wasif/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 2401, in DoUpload
    self.error_fh)
  File "/Users/wasif/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 484, in GetResourceLimits
    resource_limits.update(_GetRemoteResourceLimits(logging_context))
  File "/Users/wasif/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 454, in _GetRemoteResourceLimits
    yaml_data = logging_context.Send('/api/appversion/getresourcelimits')
  File "/Users/wasif/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 1740, in Send
    result = self.rpcserver.Send(url, payload=payload, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/wasif/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc_httplib2.py", line 228, in Send
    url, method=method, body=payload, headers=headers)
  File "/Users/wasif/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/google-api-python-client/oauth2client/client.py", line 497, in new_request
    redirections, connection_type)
  File "/Users/wasif/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/httplib2/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1584, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/Users/wasif/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/httplib2/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1332, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/Users/wasif/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/httplib2/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1306, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "/Users/wasif/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/httplib2/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1053, in connect
    raise socket.error, msg
socket.error: [Errno 65] No route to host
```

any help??

EDIT:

```
 application: maid-in-style
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:

- url: /contact.html
  script: contact.html

- url: /about.html
  script: about.html

- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: /js
  static_dir: js

- url: /pop
  static_dir: pop

- url: /pop2
  static_dir: pop2

- url: /.*
  script: index.html
```

Comment: Looks like a network problem, can you ping appengine.google.com ?

Comment: @IanGSY ping is working

Comment: What does your app.yaml file look like?

Comment: @IanGSY checkout the updated question

Answer (score 0):

That error code indicates problems with the network connection, as Ian suggested. They are not related to your application but to the network configuration you have. Maybe not allowing SSL traffic?